# duplicate order_number in commerce/orders

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a shop implement with drupal commerce, I have a problem, I have 2 method on payment method1 and method2,
in payment step, when user select method1 and go to bank to pay,it has a order record in `commerce/orders` , when the payment with method1 not  successful in `commerce/orders`  ,status is processing, after payment with method1 not successful drupal come back to payment step and if user select method2  I see another record with same order_number in `commerce/orders`, 
The problem is here when the  user accomplish payment with method2 ,  the 2 record status field will set to "completed" and manager of site dont understand finally by which method payment finished,

anybody know where is the problem and how can correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for my problem, the problem came from relation of views to product_order table, I just go to that views and revert views.
and worked